# How to create a qubit in arbitrary state in qiskit

Tags: quantum-state, qiskit

A `QuantumCircuit()` command creates a qubit with zero state always.

I've seen some instructions about using *Arbitrary Initialization* but it is not accessible and returns `404 error`.

Comment: Hi! Can you share the code you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any one-qubit state can be described as (up to a global phase):

$$|\psi \rangle = \cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right)|0\rangle + \sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right) e^{i\varphi}|1\rangle$$

If we start from $|0\rangle$ state arbitrary quantum state can be generated (up to a global phase) with $R_y(\theta)$ and $R_z(\varphi)$ unitary operators (the order is important). Firstly we apply $R_y(\theta)$

$$R_y(\theta) |0\rangle = \cos \left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right)|0\rangle + \sin \left( \frac{\theta}{2}\right)|1\rangle$$

Then $R_z(\varphi)$

$$R_z(\varphi) \left(\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)|0\rangle + \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right)|1\rangle \right) = \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)e^{-i\frac{\varphi}{2}}|0\rangle + \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)e^{i\frac{\varphi}{2}}|1\rangle$$

Disregarding the global phase we will obtain the following state:

$$|\psi \rangle = \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)|0\rangle + \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)e^{i\varphi}|1\rangle$$

That is an arbitrary state that we wanted to create. There are also other ways (gates) to this transformation.

The code will look like this:

```
circuit.ry(theta, qubit[0])
circuit.rz(phi, qubit[0])
```

It can also be done only with one [$u3(\theta, \varphi, 0)$](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/b41891aaffec0896294096cdcc24bf8c8ec6e540/qiskit/circuit/library/standard_gates/u3.py#L45-L49) gate:

$$u3(\theta, \varphi, 0) |0\rangle = \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)|0\rangle + \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)e^{i\varphi}|1\rangle$$

```
circuit.u3(theta, phi, 0, qubit[0])
```